# "print()" alternative for nodeJS

Tags: google-earth-engine, node-js

i need run this code in my nodeJS application:

```js
//Dates of Interest
var start = ee.Date("2014-10-01");
var finish = ee.Date("2018-05-01");

///--------------------- Landsat Collection ---------------------------------------///
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterDate(start, finish)
.filterBounds(roi);

// Year-Month-Day Extract function
function ymdList(imgcol){
    var iter_func = function(image, newlist){
        var date = ee.Number.parse(image.date().format("YYYYMMdd"));
        newlist = ee.List(newlist);
        return ee.List(newlist.add(date).sort())
    };
    return imgcol.iterate(iter_func, ee.List([]));
}

var ymd = ymdList(landsat);
print(ee.List(ymd).reduce(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram()));
```

But I do not know which function to use in place of "print ()", can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The typical way of logging a value in nodejs is `console.log( myValue )`. To evaluate a variable that hasn’t been computed yet, which the Earth Engine code editor does automatically when you print, you may want to define your own print function instead:

```js
var print = function (o) {
  if (o instanceof ee.ComputedObject) {
    o = o.getInfo();
  }
  console.log(o);
};
```