# Get all dates of image collection when it was created/loaded on sentinel 2 dataset

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using "COPERNICUS/S2" image collection for satellite imagery on Google Earth Engine using nodejs, I wanted to highlight the dates in calendar for particular month on which the image was created/loaded in dataset. Like the one working on EO Browser(see attached screenshot)

How can I get those dates with imageCollection?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do it on the Code Editor:

```js
var get_dates = function(collection, month, year, bounds) {
  var filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
                           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
                           .filterBounds(bounds)

  return ee.List(filtered.toList(filtered.size()).map(function(img){
    return ee.Image(img).date().format()
  }))
}

var dates = get_dates(ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2'), 1, 2017, Map.getCenter());
console.log(dates.getInfo());
```

As I have never worked with nodejs, I don't know how to do it there, but I guess is not much different.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm in Earth Engine Code Editor!  I am using nodejs(new to nodejs) to fetch those dates i dont know how i can make it work with nodejs sever side.

Comment: @rodrigo-e-principe Tried in nodejs server side and it return this instead of array
{ func: 
   { signature_: 
      { args: [Object],
        description: 'Map an algorithm over a list.  The algorithm is expected to take an Object and return an Object.',
        returns: 'List',
        type: 'Algorithm',
        hidden: false,
        name: 'List.map' } },
  args: 
   { list: { func: [Object], args: [Object], varName: null, list_: null },
     baseAlgorithm: { signature_: [Object], body_: [Object] } },
  varName: null,
  list_: null }

Comment: @NitinMuchhadiya, as I said, I have never used nodejs, but try this: `var dates = get_dates(ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2'), 1, 2017, Map.getCenter())` and then `print(dates.getInfo())`

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288614/print-alternative-for-nodejs/288745. There is no `print()` in Node.js, and the equivalent (`console.log()`) does not know about Earth Engine objects, so you need to call `.getInfo()` first. The snippet in this answer otherwise looks correct.

Comment: Thank you @DonMcCurdy! As I said I have never used nodejs, I'll modify my answer to match it.